# Splitting string into substring objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a string "FullAddress": "New Windsor,New York,USA".

I want to save only "New York,USA" from this to another string. TIA

Comment: You will get so many options to do this task with minimal googling!

Comment: So true @TejaNandamuri. I've supplied 2 answers but the list goes on and on. Without knowing the validation rules we could keep guessing all day!!!

Comment: @prasad - any feedback? can you give us more information or are the answers satisfactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string:

```
NSString *string = @"New Windsor,New York,USA";
```

You can split it by using a delimiter, in this case a comma `,`

```
NSArray *splitStrings = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

This will give you an array with 3 strings: `New Windsor`, `New York`, and `USA`. You can then manipulate and/or display these however you like. You can then manipulate and/or display these however you like. For example:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", splitStrings[1], splitStrings[2]]; // Would equal "New York,USA"
```

Answer (score 0):

No proper validation and I'm not sure what you will do to prove that the address format is as you expect but try the following:

A. Rebuild the string

```
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableString *myNewString = [NSMutableString new];
if([myArray count] > 1) {
   [myNewString appendString:myArray[1]];
}
if([myArray count] > 2) {
   [myNewString appendString:@","];
   [myNewString appendString:myArray[2]];
}
NSLog(@"This is the string you are looking for - %@", myNewString);
```

Or

B. by removing the first part

```
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *myNewString;
if([myArray count] > 1) {
    NSString *replaceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", myArray[0]];
    myNewString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: replaceString withString:@""];
} else {
    myNewString = myString;
}
```